# How to add group_concat to hsqldb with distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql, unit-testing, hsqldb, group-concat

I am trying to add the group_concat function to hsqldb so that I can properly test a query as a unit/integration test. The query works fine in mysql, so I need it to work in hsqldb (hopefully).

```
        // GROUP_CONCAT
        jdbcTemplate.update("DROP FUNCTION GROUP_CONCAT IF EXISTS;");
        jdbcTemplate.update(
            "create aggregate function group_concat(in val varchar(100), in flag boolean, inout buffer varchar(1000), inout counter int) " +
            "   returns varchar(1000) " +
            "   contains sql " +
            "begin atomic " +
            "   if flag then" +
            "      return buffer;" +
            "   else" +
            "      if val is null then return null; end if;" +
            "      if buffer is null then set buffer = ''; end if;" +
            "      if counter is null then set counter = 0; end if;" +
            "      if counter > 0 then set buffer = buffer || ','; end if;" +
            "      set buffer = buffer + val;" +
            "      set counter = counter + 1;" +
            "      return null;" +
            "   end if;" +
            "end;"
        );
```

Adding this aggregation function solves most of the problem. It will correctly behave like mysql's group_concat. However, what it won't do is let me use the distinct keyword like this:

```
group_concat(distinct column)
```

Is there any way to factor in the distinct keyword? Or do I rewrite the query to avoid the distinct keyword altogether?

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB has built-in GROUP_CONCAT and accepts DISTINCT.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_aggregate_funcs

At the moment you cannot add DISTINCT to a user-defined aggregate function, but this looks like an interesting feature to allow in the future.

Comment: I'm currently using 2.0.0, and it appears not to have it. Maybe you're referring to a newer version? I can't use the 2.2.x line - my unit tests go much, much slower for some reason when dbunit is inserting data. 2.0.0 seems to go 8-10x faster. I wrote the query to join with a sub-select that fetches the synonyms first to avoid the use of distinct. That seems to solve the problem, but I hope it's not going to make it slower.

Comment: Perhaps you need to increase JVM memory. 2.2.9 inserts 4 million rows in 12 seconds in a mem: database.